# I am trying to compress video in Android using ffmpeg

Tags: android, kotlin, video, compression, android-ffmpeg

Using this command for compressing video
val complexCommand =
" -y -i $inputFile -vcodec mpeg4 -vf "scale=-2:720" -b:v 800k -b:a 192k -ac 2 -ar 44100  -crf 18" +
"  $outputFilePath"
But this is giving bad quality. I want to have compressed video quality good and also size is smaller.

val complexCommand =
" -y -i $inputFile -vcodec mpeg4 -vf "scale=-2:720" -b:v 800k -b:a 192k -ac 2 -ar 44100  -crf 18" +
"  $outputFilePath"